# How do I log a user back in after change of Email/Username? - Asp.net/VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, cookies, asp.net-membership

I found this code on a site which was written for me and works, and I'm trying to use it on a new site. The code checks that a emailAddress doesn't already exist when a user edits their account details, and because the emailAddress is also used as the underlying .NET membership username it needs to change that too. So far I've managed to get it to change the email address in tblAccounts which is done with this call:

```
acc.UpdateUsername(txtEmailAddress.Text, lblEmailAddress.Text)
```

Then it needs to check if the user changing the email is the logged in user and re-log them back in. This doesn't seem to work as I get this error from the siteMaster when it tries to redirect to the homepage:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

The error is caused in the siteMaster when it tries to check messages for logged in user and it flags up the last line of this as where the error occurs:

```
If HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
    hypSettings.visible=true
    Dim counter As Integer = messaging.CheckUnreadMessages(Membership.GetUser.ProviderUserKey)
```

It therefore looks like the email address is being updated where it should, but the site isn't logging the user back in correctly. As I say, it works on the site where I took the code from and there isn't much difference between the sites, but I don't understand memberships and cookies too well so I'm not sure if something needs altering elsewhere?

Here's the code for changing the users email address:

```
    'Check if the Role has been changed
    Membership.ApplicationName = "/OCBS"
    Dim userID As Guid = Guid.Parse(Request.QueryString("aID"))
    Dim usr As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser(userID, False)

    'Now check if the email address has been changed, because the email address is used for the username then the underlying .NET membership username needs changing
    If txtEmailAddress.Text <> lblEmailAddress.Text Then
        'Email has been changed, update the username for this user

        Dim acc As New accounts(Guid.Empty)
        acc.UpdateUsername(txtEmailAddress.Text, lblEmailAddress.Text)

        'Check if the user changing the email is the logged in user and re-log them back in
        If User.Identity.Name = lblEmailAddress.Text Then
            'FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(txtEmailAddress.Text, False)
            Response.Cookies.Clear()
            Dim expiryDate As DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(100)
            Dim ticket As New FormsAuthenticationTicket(2, txtEmailAddress.Text, DateTime.Now, expiryDate, True, [String].Empty)
            Dim encryptedTicket As String = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket)
            Dim authenticationCookie As New HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket)
            authenticationCookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration
            Response.Cookies.Add(authenticationCookie)
        End If
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Oooh, I've managed it.. I added this..

```
Session.Abandon()
FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
```

after line: Response.Cookies.Clear()